# How to normalize numbers group?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have this in Excel, each row are increased by 5000. `AAAA` are prefix group code. In excel I highlight what is done. For example:

AAAA 1

```
AAAA 1 00000
AAAA 1 05000
AAAA 1 10000
AAAA 1 15000
AAAA 1 20000
AAAA 1 25000
AAAA 1 30000
AAAA 1 35000
AAAA 1 40000
AAAA 1 45000
```

AAAA 2

```
AAAA 2 05000
AAAA 2 10000
AAAA 2 15000
AAAA 2 20000
AAAA 2 25000
AAAA 2 30000
AAAA 2 35000
AAAA 2 40000
AAAA 2 45000
```

Prefix code can be any group of letters. After Prefix code number start from 1 to 9

What is the solution normalize this into mysql tables?  I don't want put all this in a table otherwise it will be too big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 tables . but i don't see much normalisation here ! anyway you have to keep all values in one table . do You have any factor to separate values  into many table?

```
tblprefix 

pre_id   prefix name

1         AAAAA
2         BBBBB
3         CCCCC


tblvalues


valueid   value pre_id      prefix_code
1        05000    1            2
2        40000    1            2
3        45000    1            2
```